# Adding legend to scatter plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have made a scatter plot in the following way:

```py
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(3,2)
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
ax1[0,1].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=y, s=20, marker='o', alpha=.5, cmap=cmap)
```

`data` holds the data and `y` holds the labels (1,2,3). Now I would like to add a legend.

```py
ax1[0,1].legend(('label1', 'label2', 'label3'),
           scatterpoints=1,
           loc='lower left',
           fontsize=10)
```

This does not work, it only prints label1. How can this be done otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to divide data set on separate data sets which are represented by the same color. After that the legend displayed properly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

data = np.zeros(shape=(10,2))
data[:,0] = np.linspace(0,1,10)
data[:,1] = np.linspace(0,1,10)

y = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(3,2)
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
ny = len(y)
for i, itm in enumerate(y):
    datac = data[i::ny,:]
    ax1[0,1].scatter(datac[:,0], datac[:,1], c=itm, 
                     s=20, marker='o', alpha=.5, cmap=cmap)

ax1[0,1].legend(['label1', 'label2', 'label3'],
           scatterpoints=1,
           loc='lower left',
           fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]